# Не переведена ссылка в справке про очереди проверок "Сообщения низкого качества"

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок, справка

Не переведена ссылка в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) про очереди проверок "Сообщения низкого качества":

> [image: вот даз ит мин иф э квешн из клозед]

Comment: Кроме перевода, возможно, стоит добавить закрывающую скобку (раз присутствует открывающая).